# How to set a form to prisitne state when used with custom modal dialog in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am using following directive to display a particular form (say registration form) in Angular JS.

```
.directive('modalDialog', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        show: '='
    },
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.dialogStyle = {};
        if (attrs.width)
            scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
        if (attrs.height)
            scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
        scope.hideModal = function () {
            scope.show = false;
        };
    },
    template: '<div class="ng-modal" ng-show="show">' +
              '<div class="ng-modal-overlay"></div>' +
              '<div class="ng-modal-dialog" ng-style="dialogStyle">' +
              '<div class="ng-modal-close" ng-click="hideModal()">X</div>' +
              '<div class="ng-modal-dialog-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>'
  };
});
```

Form:

```
<form class="elegant-aero" role="form"
  ng-controller="RegisterController"
  ng-submit="regForm.$valid && registerUser()"
  name="registrationForm"
  novalidate>
<div style="margin: 0 auto">
    <div class="Table">
        <div class="Title">
            <p>User Register</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">
                <label for="txtid">ID</label>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtid" name="txtid"
                       ng-model="id" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                       ng-minlength="9" ng-maxlength="9" required valid-id>
            </div>
            <div ng-messages="registrationForm.txtid.$error"
                 ng-if="registrationForm.txtid.$invalid && !registrationForm.txtid.$pristine">
                <div ng-message="required">ID is required</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">ID must have 9 characters</div>
                <div ng-message="maxlength">ID must have 9 characters</div>
                <div ng-message="validid">ID must start with E or G</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">
                <label for="txtPassword">Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword"
                       ng-model="Password" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                       ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="12" required>
            </div>
            <div ng-messages="registrationForm.txtPassword.$error" ng-if="registrationForm.txtPassword.$invalid && registrationForm.txtPassword.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">Password is required</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">Password must have atleast 6 characters</div>
                <div ng-message="maxlength">Password must have atleast 12 characters</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">
                <label for="txtConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtConfirmPassword" name="txtConfirmPassword"
                       ng-model="ConfirmPassword" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                       required compare-to="Password">
            </div>
            <div ng-messages="registrationForm.txtConfirmPassword.$error" ng-if="registrationForm.txtConfirmPassword.$invalid && registrationForm.txtConfirmPassword.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">Confirm Password field is required</div>
                <div ng-message="compareTo">Password and Confirm Password fields do not match</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">
                <label for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName"
                       ng-model="FirstName" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                       required>
            </div>
            <div ng-messages="registrationForm.txtFirstName.$error" ng-if="registrationForm.txtFirstName.$invalid && registrationForm.txtFirstName.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">First name is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">
                <label for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName"
                       ng-model="LastName" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                       required>
            </div>
            <div ng-messages="registrationForm.txtLastName.$error" ng-if="registrationForm.txtLastName.$invalid && registrationForm.txtLastName.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">Last name is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">
                <label for="txtPhone">Contact Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPhone" name="txtPhone"
                       ng-model="Phone" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                       ng-pattern="/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[ .-]?(\d{3})[ .-]?(\d{4})$/" required>
            </div>
            <div ng-messages="registrationForm.txtPhone.$error" ng-if="registrationForm.txtPhone.$invalid && registrationForm.txtPhone.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">Contact number is required</div>
                <div ng-message="pattern">Must be a valid 10 digit phone number</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <input style="margin-left: 70px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    </div>
    <div ng-show="ErrorMessage" data-ng-bind-html="ErrorMessage">

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', 'authService', '$sce', 
function ($scope, $http, $log, authService, $sce) {

    var OnRegistrationSuccess = function (data) {
        alert("Calling API");
        if (data.status == 201) {
            $scope.ErrorMessage = $sce.trustAsHtml("Registration successfull, please continue to log in");
        }
        else {
            $scope.ErrorMessage = $sce.trustAsHtml("Registration failed");
        }
    };

    var OnRegistrationFailure = function (response) {
        var errorsString = "";
        if (response != null) {
            for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
                if (response.data.modelState.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.modelState[key].length; i++) {
                        errorsString = (errorsString == "" ? "" : errorsString + "<br/>") + response.data.modelState[key][i];
                    }
                }
            }
            $scope.ErrorMessage = $sce.trustAsHtml(errorsString);
        }
        else {
            $scope.ErrorMessage = $sce.trustAsHtml("Registration failed");
        }
    };

    $scope.registerUser = function (registrationForm) {

        $scope.ErrorMessage = "";

        var userToRegister = {
            Id: $scope.id,
            Phone: $scope.Phone,
            Password: $scope.Password,
            FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
            LastName: $scope.LastName
        };

        authService.saveRegistration(userToRegister)
        .then(OnRegistrationSuccess, OnRegistrationFailure);
    };
```

}]);

AuthService:

```
.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', '$log', function ($http, $q, localStorageService, $log) {

var serviceBase = "http://localhost:8080/";
var authServiceFactory = {};

var _authentication = {
    isAuth: false,
    userName: ""
};

var _saveRegistration = function (userToRegister) {
    _logOut();

    return $http.post(serviceBase + 'api/registration/register', userToRegister,
                JSON.stringify(userToRegister),
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                }
               );
};

authServiceFactory.saveRegistration = _saveRegistration;

return authServiceFactory;
```

}]);

After successful registration I wanted to clear the contents of the form, and also if for some reason user closes and reopens the modal dialog, previous values are still being displayed. Can anyone help me to clear the contents of the form in particular events like after successful registration or hide modal?

I have tried `regForm.$setPristine()` in `ng-submit`, but it is closing the modal dialog immediately after clicking on submit button, so that user will not be able to see the status of current operation. Any hints will help me greatly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show  the form and submit code ?

Comment: I have upadted my query, pls have a look